# Звуковой перевод слов

Tags: javascript, html5

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при клике появлялось слово и оно озвучивалось.

1) Где взять эти звуки ?

2)

```
    el.onclick = function {
        word.style.display = 'block'
       //Как озвучить ?
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поищите по запросу "text to sound js api".

Например:

1. [meSpeak.js](http://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/)
2. [SpeechApi](http://www.speechapi.com/apis/javascript/)

Или используйте Google Text-to-Speech:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src ='http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf8&tl=en&q=YOUR_TEXT;
audio.play();
```

Comment: попробывал Google Text-to-Speech. Удивился тому, что audio.play() срабатывает только один раз и атрибут loop. Не работает.
Если задавать src на локальный файл, то все ок.